# necesito generar un subcadena en el lenguaje prolog

Tags: prolog

tengo un programa que me saca sufijos y prefijos,pero ahora quiero generar una sub-cadena y aun  no entiendo el lenguaje de prolog.

solo tengo esto:

```
principio:-
    write("Queremos saber cual es la cadena "),
    read(Cad),
    string_chars(Cad,Lista),
    write(Lista),
    length(Lista,Tam),
    write("&"),nl,
    prefijos(Lista,0,Tam),
    reverse(Lista,Listainv),nl,
    length(Lista,Nte),
    espacios(Nte),
    write("&"),nl,
    sufijos(Listainv,0,Tam).

imprimir([]).
imprimir([Ca|Co]):-
    write(Ca),
    imprimir(Co).

espacios(0).
espacios(Ne):-
    write("  "),
    Nef is Ne-1,
    espacios(Nef).

obtener(_,0,Ls,Tam):-
    length(Ls,Tax),
    Ce is Tam-Tax,
    espacios(Ce),
    imprimir(Ls),
    nl.

obtener(Lista,Nsuf,Ls,Tam):-
    Lista=[Ca|Cola],
    Lsa=[Ca|Ls],
    Nsufa is Nsuf-1,
    obtener(Cola,Nsufa,Lsa,Tam).

sufijos(_,Nsuf,Tam):-
      Nsuf>Tam.

sufijos(Lista,Nsuf,Tam):-

        obtener(Lista,Nsuf,[],Tam),
    Nsufa is Nsuf+1,
    sufijos(Lista,Nsufa,Tam).


reducir(_,0):-
    nl,!.

reducir(Vector,Nupre):-
    Vector=[Cab|Cola],
    write(Cab),
    Nuprea is Nupre-1,
    reducir(Cola,Nuprea).

prefijos(Vector,Nupre,Cont):-
    Nupre=<Cont,
    reducir(Vector,Nupre),
    Nuprea is Nupre+1,
    prefijos(Vector,Nuprea,Cont).

prefijos(_,_,Cont):-
    tab(5),
    write("El total de prefijos fue "),
    write(Cont).
```

Comment: Hola Juanita, te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: @JuanitaChavez puedes poner ejemplos de las subcadenas porfavor.

Comment: ok, por ejemplo, es que mi programa hace esto:

Comment: ok, por ejemplo, es que mi programa hace esto: principio.
Queremos saber cual es la cadena "mario".
[m,a,r,i,o]&

m
ma
mar
mari
mario
     El total de prefijos fue 5
          &
          
        o
      io
    rio
  ario
mario
true .                       (de aqui quiero sacar la subcadena , que cuando me de la cadena me valla restando letras, asi deberia quedar, mario,mari,mar,ma,m......ario,ari,ar,a......rio,ri,r,....io,o.....o

Comment: @JuanitaChavez podés incluir cualquier información extra en la pregunta haciendo click en **[edit]** (que está al pie de la misma)... y se lee mucho mejor que en un comentario

Answer (score 0):

```
iniciar:-
    write("Ingrese la cadena "),
    read(C),nl,
    string_chars(C,Cad),
    length(Cad,Len),
    subCadena(Cad,Len).
```

%Esta logica es similar a un bloque iterativo anidado en programacion estructurada, por ejemplo un DO While dentro de un DO While.

```
subCadena(_,0):-
    write("FINAL").
subCadena([H|T],Len):-
    subC([H|T],Len),
    Lenn is Len - 1,
    subCadena(T,Lenn).

subC(_,0):-nl.
subC(Cad, Len):-
    string_codes(String,Cad),
    write(String),write(".."),
    Lenn is Len - 1,
    reverse(Cad,[_|T]),
    reverse(T,L),
    subC(L,Lenn).
```

Saludos.